# PresentModalViewController takes 5 secs to bring up the modal

Tags: iphone, ios, modalviewcontroller, uiactivityindicatorview, uipagecontrol

I am trying to present a modal vc. But it takes like 5 secs or so n the delay appears to be significant as the user tries to tap on the button un till they see some thing on the screen.

My Modal view has 3 pages and each page has 6 tables as subviews. I am not using any network connectivity. All the tables are loaded from local xml data.

So, my questions are 
     1)is there a way i can improve the performance of the loaded modal vc?
     2)or can i show an activity indicator and let the view load on a background thread and      remove the indicator once the load is complete?

I tried option 2. I started the activity indicator on    *viewDidLoad* and all the page Initialization code in a background thread using    *performSelectorInBackground* method. But, this is making my tables to look weird like, there frame is all distorted , there width is screwed up n so on. Any suggestions will really help  ma lot.

Answer (score 2):

Never show or modify interface elements in a background thread.  If you're in a background thread and you want to do something in the main thread, you can either use a selector:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(doSomething:)
                       withObject:someObject
                    waitUntilDone:NO];
```

or you can use GCD (my favorite):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self doSomething:someObject];
});
```

Regardless of which method you use, just make sure that if you load your data in a background thread and then try to load a view from that background thread, always do that call on the main thread, otherwise you will get the weird behavior you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. This solves one puzzle for me. But, if i perform on my main thread the load is going to be delayed again and i cant show the activity indicator.

Comment: @jacob: Performing something on the main thread isn't going to stop your background threads.  What you need to do is perform your xml parsing in a background thread, then have a callback when that's done that will launch the modal view on the main thread.

Comment: The delay is not from loading the data as I m loading them from local xml files. It is majorily coz of number of subviews i m generating and adding on the viewDidLoad.

Comment: Well loading a view in a background thread is never the way to do it.  It will destroy your performance, if not crash your app.  Try to optimize your subviews and/or images.

Answer (score 0):

You can show activity indicator on viewDidAppear and then fetch data in background thread and you just need to refresh your view/tableview. This way modal view will not 5 seconds or delay when presented.

Comment: This does not help me in wat so ever manner. Please go through the problem again before you answer. My delay is not coz of data fetching, all the data is in local xml. It is coz of the number of subvviews that I have in each page.